# Magento: Set a product to not be visible in search or catalog but the url still exist

Tags: magento

I have a client request when a product is discontinued to make it so that product is not visible in catalog or search but the url and product still exists and you just can't order the product.

The only visibility options are catalog,search, catalog and search, not visible individually. If I just set the value to blank will it not be visible in catalog and search but still exist?

Is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**
As Clockwork says below as long as you have it set in the configuration to not show out of stock products this is default functionality to keep the url and not show up in categories and search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reduce it's stock to 0 and make sure it is 'Out Of Stock'. In System > Configuration > Inventory > Stock Options make sure 'Display Out of Stock Products' is 'No'. That will allow the page to display without being purchasable.

If you must have 'Display Out of Stock' on then set the product's visibility to 'Catalog' and remove it from all categories. It will then have no more links to it without being completely disabled.

Comment: Thanks clock, I will give it a shot in the morning. Looks to be the answer though

Comment: Yeah, I guess that was stupid of me, since this is the default functionality :)

Comment: Yes while setting this does take it out of the view, it's an ugly kludge. It may work, but it's so not a good idea.

Comment: @baash05 If you have a better answer then post it as one, maybe dan.codes will see it your way and change his choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a product with the visibility field set to Catalog, and don't assign it to any categories.
This way no one will be able to find it while browsing the catalog and it won't be visible when a search is made, but you will still be able to access it via a link.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's a long time but just for fun i publish a module for this purpose.
it will add "product" to catalog product visibility
[image]

https://github.com/gh-darvishani/product-visibility